# How to Send to View `$data` and `$data2_cat2` at same time?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter, and I'm experiencing an issue on how to send to view `$data` and `$data_cat2` at same time?

```
    $data['records'] = $this->gallery_model->get_all(1);
    $data_cat2['records'] = $this->gallery_model->get_all(2);

    $this->load->view('gallery/index.php',$data);
```

I tried to use `$this->load->view` for `$data_cat2`, and it just repeated the information on the page. Does anyone know of anything to help solve this issue? Thanks in advance!

---

**Update**:

I apologize for the silly question, as I just figured it out using the following:

```
    $data['records'] = $this->gallery_model->get_all(1);
    $data['records_cat2'] = $this->gallery_model->get_all(2);
```

In accordance with `record_cat2` in the view file.

Answer (score 0):

Also, for passing variables outside the `load->view()` method, use:

```
$this->load->vars(array('records' => $data, 'records_cat2' => $data_cat2));
$this->load->view('gallery/index');
```